# How literate were common people in Medieval Europe?

Tags: middle-ages, europe

I stumbled upon a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/-abyQLl8mPI) some time ago about literacy in Medieval Europe. The guy argues that probably at least one person per household was able to read - contrary to common belief. His arguments are basically, that a) learning to read is not that hard, and b) it is really, really helpful if you can read and maybe even write. This sounds very reasonable to me.

On the other hand, when you look at London gutters around 1800, most of the poor people couldn't read, which would exclude them from promotion as a soldier to higher ranks. I got this from Bernard Cornwell's [Sharpe series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpe_(novel_series)). The books seems to be very well researched, so I believe the presented information.

Now the question: Was it really likely that in Medieval times the common people could read and 750 years later, the poor couldn't? Of course there are many other side-effects I didn't consider in this question but I'd be interested in your opinion.

Would be glad for some food of thought on this topic.

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that books only became available (affordable) to the lowest classes relatively recently. Schooling for all is also relatively recent. It's easy to learn to read when you have teachers and parents who can read and there are plenty of things available for you to read. It's not so easy when the only books are at the church and they are written in Latin.

Comment: Can you summarize why it would be helpful for a commoner to be able to read?  I'm skeptical.  Literacy rates were [below 20%](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1290524.pdf) [multiple similar conclusions](https://www.quora.com/What-were-literacy-rates-in-Medieval-Europe-How-did-they-compare-to-literacy-rates-in-the-Roman-Empire)   What would they read? to whom would they write?

Comment: Damn good question. I actually asked a variant of this one myself of a bunch of experts on twitter last week.

Comment: I don't know who told you that at least one person per household was able to read, but I would be surprised if it was true. Two things to consider: books were remarkably expensive before the printing press and almost only monks could write and they were spending a large portion of their time copying books and most of the written text was in Latin that common people didn't really understand

Comment: Medieval Europe is huge both geographically and in time. The answer will be very different between Poland in 600 and Italy in 1300...

Comment: Here are some numbers: By 1700 in France, 30% of men and 14% of women could sign civil registers; by 1800, the percentages had grown to 47% and 27%, and to 83% and 73% by 1881. See ["Teaching Literacy in the West from the Middle Ages to the 21st Century"](https://oxfordre.com/education/view/10.1093/acrefore/9780190264093.001.0001/acrefore-9780190264093-e-1652) and references therein. I do not have time to dig through the books and papers references there.

Comment: As other comments have said, don't underestimate the importance of *having something to read*. Never mind whole books - some peasants probably went their whole lives without seeing *words* written down in any form. The availability of reading material is of course a necessary precondition for teaching people to read. In modern times people can and sometimes do teach themselves to read without any schooling, which medieval peasants couldn't do.

Comment: The printing press is overrated.  It would get nowhere without cheap paper.  And they also didn't have cheap paper.  Vellum was wonderful for preserving documents for a long time -- unlike papyrus, which lasted barely a century except in ideal conditions -- but it did begin by calculating how many ewes you had to breed.

Comment: You might compare modern societies with a large number of illiterate people, e.g. Afghanistan. Even there it is true that learning to read is not terribly hard if you have someone patiently explain it to you. But IMHO the assumption that reading is very very useful may not hold.

Comment: Wow! Not used to so many replies! And just to make it clear: I don't believe 100% was some dude at youtube says. I said: The reasoning sounded logical to me. 

Comment: While the argument may be sound logically, the premises may be false.

Comment: @MCW There could be many reasons to read and write in the basic day to day life and businness. See the amount of ordinary lifetexts in Old Novgorod https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_bark_manuscript#East_Slavic_texts  It helps when the only literally language isn't just Latin, though. In Bohemia, for example, Czech literature only appeared in the 14th century.

Comment: I'm skeptical of the scholarship behind Shadversity videos; we've had several questions about Shadversity.  His conclusions frequently challenge commonly held and well researched conclusions, but, in my experience, rarely support this with scholarship.  My inclination is to accept citations over common sense.

Comment: @MCW There are many birch-bark manuscripts from medieval Veliky Novgorod. Most of them in the local dialect and most of them dealing with the daily life and businness. Ordinary notes and messages from someone to someone. BTW., the said region is in Europe.

Comment: Worth pointing out that literacy is far from a binary literate/illiterate thing and many people who can read a simple text if they concentrate are still functionally illiterate enough to be substantially limited in modern society. I imagine many people in the Middle Ages would be able to read a sentence if they cared to try, but without the regular practice of reading they'd have no habit for doing so automatically as soon as they see writing, and likely rarely bother

Comment: I'd also like to point out that, outside some specific areas of expertise (e.g. fortifications) Shad of Shadiversity (who produced the linked video) is often wildly unreliable, and often does a very poor job distinguishing between his own speculations and well-researched opinion, and when called out on these inaccuracies has often responded in an unscholarly way (just doubling down and not acknowledging his actual shortcomings)

Comment: @NeMo I can image that would be a small minority. Signs and placards have been common in everyday life in most parts of Europe since the Romans. Milestones would have been found on most major roads, otherwise travellers would end up very lost!

Comment: @Crazymoomin: There are methods to find your way without road signs, e.g. asking other people for the way.

Comment: @Jan If there's anyone around to ask! A traveller could be waiting a very long time...

Comment: @Crazymoomin There would probably be people in the fields or at least in the next village.

Comment: It seems about half of the UK population was literate in 1800 (and almost all in 1900).  [*Education, Literacy and the Reading Public* by Amy J. Lloyd](https://www.gale.com/binaries/content/assets/gale-us-en/primary-sources/intl-gps/intl-gps-essays/full-ghn-contextual-essays/ghn_essay_bln_lloyd3_website.pdf) says "In
1800 around 40 percent of males and 60 percent of
females in England and Wales were illiterate; by 1900
illiteracy for both sexes had dropped to around 3
percent."

Comment: **1500 AD : 10%** of men and hardly any women" - **1800 AD : 40 percent** of males and 60 percent of females in England. **1900 AD : 97%**

Comment: I was taught at school that in 15-16th century, 50% of all women in Poland could read, and 10% of total polulation could communicate in Latin. This is just a comment as I don't have any sources.

Comment: >The guy argues that probably at least one person per household was able to read

What is "one household"? Assuming nuclear family of one father, one mother and 3 children (I have no actual demographical data on hand right now but I think to recall that having 3 or more children was non unusual), then if the father can read, this means that 20% of the family's population is literate.  The Quora that @MCW linked to claim between 15% and 25% of literacy in XIII century. So statistically speaking, it is doable. My point being, 25% of literacy is vastly different from 4% during "Dark Ages".

Comment: @Crazymoomin _...Signs and placards have been common ... since the Romans..._ You do know that The Life of Brian's _Romanes Eunt Domus_ sketch is not actually history, yeah?

Comment: @OscarBravo Yes, I'm basing my argument on archeological evidence. Here's a good site documenting most of what has been found: https://romaninscriptionsofbritain.org/sites/map. Of course, anything written or carved on a perishable material, such as wood, would likely not have survived, so it's reasonable to suppose that this is only a fraction of what was present in Roman Britain.

Comment: @Jan Depends on where you are. Not everywhere in the UK is densely populated, even more so back in the Medieval era. You could be walking for at least an hour to get to the nearest settlement, so being able to navigate without assistance would be very useful.

Answer (score 42):

Here are some semi-random quotes. I do not have time to chase the references, but they are coming from a modern professional historian, not from a You-tube personality, so I'd take his numbers seriously.

Robert A. Houston,  "[The Growth of Literacy in Western Europe from 1500 to 1800](https://brewminate.com/the-growth-of-literacy-in-western-europe-from-1500-to-1800/)".

Houston is a professor of History at St.Andrews and wrote a book on the subject:

"Literacy in Early Modern Europe: Culture and Education, 1500–1800," London 2001.

> Literacy is a relative concept that has meaning only in specific economic and social contexts, but historians tend to rely on universal, standard and direct indicators such as the ability to sign one’s name on a document. Using this measure it is clear that there were social distinctions in the ability to use a writing instrument throughout the early modern period.

> **At the end of the Middle Ages, the ability to write was restricted to less than 10% of men and hardly any women possessed it.**

> The change in literacy rates was halting and irregular. Judged by signing, the most pronounced early expansion occurred among the middle and upper classes, among men and in towns. In northern England the illiteracy of the gentry fell from about 30% in 1530 to almost nil in 1600, but that of day labourers stayed well above 90%.

You can find more numbers in his article (in particular, numbers in relation to different areas of Western and Central Europe). Yes, the ability to read is different from the ability to write, but in Houston's statistics he focuses on the ability to just write own name, which is the bare minimum of literacy and (IMHO) probably was highly correlated with the ability to read (at least in some language, be this Latin or vernacular).

**Edit 1.** Regarding Mark Olson's request, below are estimates of literacy at the end of the medieval times/early modern times from other authors.

All the books that I found which deal with numerical estimates of literacy in late medieval and early modern times favor the ability to sign as an estimator of the degree of literacy. In addition to Houston's book (whose book has the entire chapter comparing different methods, including ones which I find rather exotic, such as materials of Spanish Inquisition trials):

D. Cressy, *Literacy and the Social Order*. Cambridge University Press, 1980.

R. O'Day, *Education and Society, 1500-1800: The Social Foundations of Education in Early Modern Britain*. Longman, 1982.

Adam Fox, "Oral and Literate Culture in England, 1500–1700." Oxford University Press, 2000.

Cressy is especially thorough with providing numerical data and its statistical analysis.

Day compares for instance the analysis of literacy in Northern England in

Jo Ann Hoeppner Moran. "Literacy and Education in Northern England, 1350-1530: A Methodological Inquiry." Northern History, 17 (1981): 1-23.

based on estimates of the number of parochial schools and argues that Cressy's methodology is provides more reliable estimates.

On page 20 of her book O'Day says that Moran's numbers indicate that 15% of the total population of York diocese had undergone basic schooling by 1530, while Cressy indicates 10%.

O'Day characterizes as "wildly optimistic" the estimates of 30% literacy in the late 15th century.

Moran's article is the only one that I found which provides numerical estimates of literacy in England in 13-15th centuries. She notes, however, lack of extant records and bases her estimates on availability of schooling (making the numbers less reliable, at least according to O'Day).

Some of Moran's research results are summarized by O'Day as follows:

> From this source [availability of schooling] she concludes that some 15% of the population of York diocese attended a school in the late 15th century, as compared with perhaps 9% in the early 15th century and some 4.7% in the late 14th century. But it may be suspected that these figures err considerably on the generous side. Dr. Moran based these estimates on calculations which assumed a regular and constant size for the schools concerned. Later evidence suggests that consistency in this respect was not a feature of early schools.

From reading Cressy's book, I think, I found the original source of the claim that about half of English population by the end of 15th century was literate. He attributes the number to Thomas More:

[image]

Cressy then proceeds:

[image]

While Cressy's book contains mass of numerical data related to literacy (based on various archival work), it is all broken into subcategories according to occupation and geography and, in the book, I could not find aggregate overall numbers. But, in his later paper, from 1993, "Literacy in context: meaning and measurement in early modern England", Cressy writes:

[image]

Thus, according to **this** estimate, the rate of literacy in mid-16th century England was about 12.5%.

Another estimate (dealing with the end of the medieval time and, thus, closer to the OP), based on the signage records appears in

Adam Fox, "Oral and Literate Culture in England, 1500–1700." Oxford University Press, 2000.

[image]

Based on the early arguments from Schofields 1973 article (which is widely cited and described as the breakthrough leading to transition from qualitative to quantitative estimates in literacy during early modern times), Fox then estimates that these numbers should be doubled to get an estimate of the **reading** capacity, thus, getting:

**10% adult male reading and 2% adult female reading in England in 1500.**

---

**Lastly, regarding criticisms of usage of signage as a mean of estimating rates of literacy (ability to read) in late medieval/early modern times:**

1. In their books O'Day, Cressy and Houston analyze in detail other available methods, note merits and demerits of each and, in the end, conclude in favor of signage. (This again follows Schofield's 1973 article.) In particular, they do discuss arguments similar to the one in Adam Baker's comment below, suggesting that for some people signing with a symbol/picture instead of the written name was a choice rather than the result of illiteracy. Reproducing these arguments here would take too much space and my answer is already too long, so I will refrain from doing so.
2. I am unsure about the origin of the claim that (generically) women were prohibited from "signing anything." I **do not** exclude that this was indeed the case in **some** places and at **certain** times. However, as fas as late medieval/early modern England goes, the claim  is plain wrong. For instance Cressy documents striking difference in signage among women in London and elsewhere by the late 17th century: The percentage for both categories started near zero in 1500 and increased only to about 20% outside of London by the late 17th century. At the same time, in London, it reached about 50% by late 17th century. As far as I can tell, this dynamics completely invalidates the conjecture that women (at least in the discussed time period) were prohibited from signing their names.

Ditto the numbers provided by Houston in his article and the book for other parts of Europe: They indicate slow (but uneven) growth of female literacy (as measured by name signage) elsewhere in Europe, indicative of improvement of education rather than abolishing of some laws prohibiting signage.

Comment: But the ability to write one's name is not the same as the ability to write. It's the first thing children learn, and you don't need to understand what it means, it's just a pattern. It's just one step up from "X, his mark".

Comment: @RedSonja: Of course! The **inability** to sign own name is a very strong indicator of inability to read.

Comment: @MoisheKohan It might have been inability or it might have been preference. There's an interpretive step in assuming that everyone who could have signed his name would have done so.

Comment: @adam.baker: One can imagine various scenarios here, of course. However, what would be **your** favorite way, as a modern historian, to estimate (however inaccurately) the percentage of people in the past who can read (say, just know the letters of alphabet and what sounds they roughly correspond to)? I am not even asking about **understanding** what they are reading. I know few more, documentable ones, but they are much more interpretive than signage.

Comment: There's a major failure in this methodology though.  Signing for anything requires the *authority* to sign for it.  Only widows had any authority, or even personal possessions; unmarried women were under the complete authority of their father, and married women were under the complete authority of their husband.  In fact there are major problems finding any documentary evidence even of women's existence between birth, marriage and death, never mind evidence of their lifestyles. Honestly, I have to ask whether a historian who'd miss this can really be taken seriously.

Comment: @Graham: Interesting: What country and what time period are you talking about?

Comment: While I like that he gave a number that touches the Middle Ages (just barely), in a perfect world it would be nice to have an idea about the Early and High Middle Ages as well. My swag based on quantity of surviving sources is that it would be a much (perhaps frighteningly) smaller number in the EMA, but it could be that the 10% is pretty much stable-state for a Feudal system.

Comment: @T.E.D.: One would have to dig through more sources for that.

Comment: Those quotes might be good, but they seem to report the conclusion on one scholar, and don't give much of a hint at how well supported they are.

Comment: @MarkOlson: I have similar conclusions from others, how many do you need? BTW, Houston's main specialty is the history of literacy.

Comment: @MarkOlson: I added more references. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 11):

*The Light Ages* by Seb Falk writes, “Literacy was not as rare in medieval England as is often assumed — around half the population had a basic level, sufficient to read a familiar prayer” (pg. 30). (This is a book written for a popular audience, but written by a proper historian.)

I will also register a different opinion from Moishe as to the correlation of the ability to read and the ability to write. I read several languages fluently that I cannot write in the least, and I read one language where learning to write was very clearly a distinct skill. (It's harder to come up with the spelling of a word than to recognize it. Letter formation in a distinct skill. etc.)

Comment: I think controversies about literacy levels in the past are quite common, with high and low estimates differing by an order of magnitude or so. I also can read cyrillic and arabic letters quite well and am very bad at writing, but 1. I would be able to write my (very simple) name if i had too, and 2. my signature is always in latin letters.

Comment: I am wondering about what is meant by the part in parantheses. E.g. Persian has a somewhat difficult orthography in that there two to four possible letters each for some very common sounds, but the question is not about correctness of orthography. Chinese characters are quite hard to memorize, but I think we can agree that Chinese is not a good analogy to English when it comes to the ease of learning to read and write.

Comment: @Jan My only point in the second paragraph is that it shouldn't be assumed that one's ability to read can't straightforwardly be determined by whether one can write (or in this case, sign his/her own name). And signing one's name isn't a great proxy for ability to write. If I had to, I could write out my name in any of the orthographies I know; but if I had an option, and if there weren't a particular stigma to being unable to write, maybe I would choose to make a thumbprint or an X, or whatever.

Comment: On the other hand, I read of a literacy program that only taught people to sign their names, so that they would have a larger number of beneficiaries. Many scenarios are conceivable. :-)

Comment: It makes me wonder how did Falk got his "half the population" estimate: In the book he provides no footnotes or endnotes to support this number. (The reference at the end of the paragraph is to the St.Alban's entry requirements.)

Comment: My question is, if literacy was more common than assumed, what was the value of being literate to someone who lived his entire life in the same village: no need to read road signs or signs on buildings or tax forms, etc. As far as religion, many people who regularly pray and sing religious songs have memorized these. Books were  very rare. So I do wonder why anyone who was not a priest or a doctor would bother even learning  the alphabet although they might learn Roman numerals. This level of illiteracy existed much later in the USA -- people made their mark instead of writing own names.

Comment: @releseabe That's a good question to be asking. I lived in the developing world for a time, and there are wealthy, successful people who are entirely illiterate. They thought no more of having someone else do their reading and writing than you and I would think of having an accountant do our taxes. (This depends on society being set up a certain way, of course. I wouldn't try it in America!)

Comment: @adam.baker: I know people in the USA who know letters of alphabet, but I doubt have read a book as an adult. Such people could probably slowly, perhaps reading out loud, manage to get through some pages; expecting them to even write a letter (let alone an essay) that does not sound child like, simply due to lack of practice, is unrealistic. Semi-illiteracy today is probably much more common than one thinks. A bartender I knew was pulled over by cops and asked to recite the alphabet backwards and he honestly said he doubted he could do it forwards -- these memorized things fade with disuse.

Comment: @Jan - Controversies about Medieval European literacy are *particularly* ongoing. The sense I get is that there's currently a scholarly counter-reaction to the popular conception of "The Dark Ages", and it has become such a *cause* that there's perhaps a good amount of *overreaction* going on. You hear some numbers bandied about (like this one, that IMHO lowers the bar into the dirt) that are actually **higher** than the first real survey numbers we have from places like France in the 1800's.

Comment: @T.E.D I have read similar stuff re. literacy in pre-modern China and also in pre-modern (Outer) Mongolia, so it is not limited to Europe. The thing about Mongolia was in a book from the 1960s, so it is not entirely a new thing either. The point about counter-reaction may be on spot, though.

Comment: (note that for discussing literacy, pre-modern Mongolia and pre-modern China are really two different worlds, despite geographical and political similarities. With very different social dynamics and very different writing systems)

Comment: I suspect the reason they're using writing as a proxy is simply because it leaves a record.

Comment: @Barmar - Well, also in order to have something to read, someone has to first have written it. If I find no bridles, saddles, or stirrups from an era, it seems logical that probably not a lot of people there could ride, even though most riders can't create those things.

Comment: @T.E.D. The analogy doesn't seem apt, since the skills required for riding are very different from those required for manufacturing saddles. But reading and writing skills are very closely aligned, and often taught together.

Comment: "Sufficient to read a familiar prayer" - is it really literacy when you can only read things if you already know what they say? I've seen very young children recite a favorite book word-for-word from memory when cued by the book pages, but I wouldn't consider that literacy. I'm curious what level of literacy that really represents.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The thing is, at school, you are taught to read letters. And then perhaps syllables. But in reality, any proficient reader reads (familiar) words at once, and quite often entire phrases. Kids _before_ school can get really good at reading familiar words even though they can't read letters at all. The way reading is _taught_ doesn't really follow how people teach _themselves_ to read (I was self-taught). I wouldn't be surprised if this was the case for medieval literacy too - people could read a (couple?) hundred words. "Literate" meant "read latin" back then anyway.

Comment: @Luaan this is getting really off-topic, but the idea that learning to recognize hundreds or thousands of whole words is simpler than learning to read letter by letter is controversial, to say the least. I am sure this works for "MUM", but quickly becomes undoable as words become longer.

Answer (score 11):

Other answers are mostly about England. The Middle Ages were very long with several different stages. Europe is also huge.

While in the Early Middle Ages the Carolingian renaissance already flourished in one part of Europe, among Slavs virtually no-one could read or write, except for a handful of mainly Iro-scot missionaries. Mind you, this is not just "somewhere in Russia", but also in the regions that include today's Berlin or today's Hungary. Even in the West (Franconia), literacy was limited to the members of the church.

Later in the Middle Ages traces of surprisingly high literacy were discovered in some areas. A very notable example are the [birch bark manuscripts of Veliky Novgorod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_bark_manuscript#East_Slavic_texts). They were only discovered in the 1950s and were extremely surprising. They show that even ordinary people used birch bark to log notes or to deliver simple ordinary messages from someone to someone. Of course, velum or paper and ink were way too expensive for such purposes for ordinary people. The local environment is favourable for preserving these artefacts. We do not know to which extent this may or may not have extended to wider areas. The existence of Church Slavic, similar enough to the local East Slavic vernacular, as a literally language have certainly helped.

It is perhaps also right to mention the Hussite movement in the 1420s and 1430s. It all began even earlier when Bibles translated to vernacular (Old Czech editions) became common enough and individual non-church-appointed preachers appeared travelling in the country and interpreting it. This were still mostly people with university (there was one in Prague since 1348) or other higher education and the Bibles were still relatively expensive  manuscripts.

There are many historiographical works that have dealt with this problem. Most are currently unreachable to me, but I will give a link to an overview of such literature:

[Mostert, M. (1999). A bibliography of works on medieval communication. In New Approaches to Medieval Communication (pp. 193-318) https://doi.org/10.1484/M.USML-EB.3.4838](https://doi.org/10.1484/M.USML-EB.3.4838)

it is really just a long list (1580 titles) of bibliography, but many of those cited works should be about this very topic. It obviously does not contain any new research from the 21st century.

---

In the introduction of one of the quoted works: [Bäuml (1980) Varieties and consequences of medieval literacy and illiteracy](https://doi.org/10.2307/2847287) the author repeats that the medieval literacy was mostly the Latin one (implicitly limiting themselves - at least in the introduction - to the West and to the earlier periods before vernacular literatures in the late Middle ages) and also mentions one of the arguments that was repeated here, that the ability to read and the ability to write are not necessarily dependent on each other.

The same author in [Scribe et Impera: Literacy in Medieval Germany (1997)](https://doi.org/10.11588/fr.1997.1.60674) shows how the literacy and the Latin language vs. the vernacular language influenced different layers of the society and led to "heresies" such as the Hussite movement in Bohemia that I mentioned above:

> ... The gradual spread of vernacular writtenness, gathering speed in
> the twelfth Century and becoming a flood with the inven- tion of
> printing ... . The translations of Christian texts from Latin into the
> vernacular during the Carolingian era served to establish the power of
> the Church on German territory. The layman was involved in these
> vernacular literarifications merely as listener to readings and
> observer of liturgical performances. There was no question of his
> having any direct access to writtenness - he had no need for it,
> unless it be as a member of the governing religious or secular
> establishment. During the Ottonian period, when the Christianization
> of what had become the Holy Roman Empire had been largely achieved,
> very little was produced in vernacular writing, if its transmission is
> any guide. With the twelfth Century, however, and in concert with the
> increasing rationalization of territorial governance, there began an
> increase in vernacular writtenness. Access of the laity to the written
> word, and particularly to religious texts, therefore also increased.
> This threatened the clerical monopoly of written knowledge, including
> its monopoly of the written Word of God, at the same time as it
> strengthened the laity’s selfconfidence in the face of that monopoly.
> Students and professors, attracted to the growing universities founded
> by lay powers to provide them with secular and religious knowledge,
> found that it was in their interest to Support the clerical monopoly
> of knowledge. In the later Middle Ages, in the fifteenth Century,
> municipal schools teaching writing (in German) and bookkeeping were
> founded as the necessity for literacy in business law, in business
> management and in business generally increased. Monastic and religious
> reformers of every stripe demanded more books and better access to
> books, and mystics of every stripe produced a steady stream of written
> material in the vernacular. And the Church soon saw heretics lurking
> in every corner.

---

All the above is about free people. People from the cities like merchants (or their children), free people owning a few villages and so on. Or even poor but free people like those travelling preachers. There is little hope in assuming that the non-free peasants (serfs) had the opportunity to learn to read or write anything. And if, then not in significant numbers.

Answer (score 9):

There is an interesting publication, "[Literacy and Education in England 1640-1900" by Lawrence Stone in 1969](https://www.jstor.org/stable/650183). (If SciHub suits you, you can search there for that internet address.) It focuses on England, but also glances elsewhere in Western Europe. It does not stray back into the medieval period, which may be the main focus of the question, but it may give some insights for that period (and the question itself seems interested in later centuries as well). Here are some snippets from that paper:

The Protestation Returns of 1642 [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestation_Returns_of_1641%E2%80%931642) gave an almost complete survey of adult males, with signatures or marks. (There is discussion about how well literacy can be judged by the ability to write your own name, and the hope is that the connection is not bad. Remember that people are writing their names many years after they left school.) "One may tentatively conclude that the average male literacy rate on the eve of the Civil War was probably not less than 30 per cent, varying from 15 to 20 per cent in the rural north and west to up to 40 per cent in the countryside near London; and that the rate in some of the larger towns of the south was as high as 60 per cent."

Some breakdown between classes is attempted. For marriage records in Oxfordshire and Gloucestershire, there is very little change for the "labouring and servant" class from 1675 to 1800: literacy stays around 45% (except for a sharp dip around 1775, probably due to population growth). Meanwhile, the "yeomen/husbandmen" class rose from 55% to 90%. In that class, the marriage records go back to 1625, and there was a large but inexplicable disparity between the two neighbouring counties: 68% literacy in Glos. versus <40% in Oxon. However, these marriage records correspond to an expensive way to get married, and "the bottom half of the population is barely represented in this sample". (An amusing side comment: "It cannot be argued that the licensing system was favoured by couples in cases where the bride was already pregnant and therefore in a hurry, since it looks as if at least one third and possibly up to a half of all brides were in this condition anyway in the eighteenth century.")

One theme in the paper is that advances in literacy were often pushed by religious groups and in particular by religious rivalry. England's literacy may have benefitted from Protestantism, with its encouragement of Bible study. Scotland did even better with Presbyterians in charge of education. "Some puritan sects became 100 per cent literate at a very early stage: in post-1754 Quaker marriage registers, there is not a single mark to be seen, by either bridegroom or bride." School policy and funding are responsible for the eventual rises. The flipside of this is that without organised, funded and obligatory schooling, the natural rate of self-taught literacy was low. The other big opponent to child literacy was pressure to start work. Sometimes the ruling classes deliberately avoided teaching the lower classes literacy, to avoid heresy, discontent and revolution. These factors combine in some records for Beziers-Narbonne in France, 1575-1593: unskilled rural workers signed their names only 3% of the time (though another 7% wrote their initials). At around the same time, artisans in Montpellier were signing 63% of the time (plus 11% initialling).

There are some hints that literacy pre-Reformation and pre-printing was not common at all: "The parish priests of late medieval England were often illiterate. [...] Between a quarter and a third of the parish clergy owned at least one or two service books. [...] Of 311 clergy of the diocese of Gloucester in 1551, 168 were unable to repeat the Ten Commandments."

One last foray towards the medieval period: "In the Middle Ages literacy carried with it no special sense of status, since many of the highest nobles in the land could neither read nor write. In northern Europe, the end of this phase came in the mid-sixteenth century: the first earl of Rutland in England and the Constable Montmorency in France were the last illiterates to hold high office in their respective countries."

Comment: Solid contribution - I question whether the date (1642) is within the [medieval period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Ages); it is not implausible that the 15-20% literacy rates offered in other answers would, by 1642, in combination with the educated classes, result the 30% literacy suggested in this paper.

Comment: I like answers with numbers and explanations of where they came from!

Comment: @MCW -- I agree with your comments. (I mentioned at the start that the paper does not really overlap with the medieval period but has some wider lessons.) I think the educated class was really a very small minority at the time, though.

Comment: At the risk of prolixity, the estimates I've seen are in the realm of 15%; so long as we're talking about the boundary of the medieval and reformation period, I'd err on the high sides of those estimates.  Another issue that probably deserves more attention is urban vs rural; you mention this in your answer, and I think further exploration could significantly clarify the situation.

Comment: Another support for religion in education : John Knox, at the tail end of the medieval era (1560s) was proposing laws for universal education of children. https://www.ed.ac.uk/education/about-us/maps-estates-history/history/part-one#:~:text=John%20Knox%20in%201560%20outlined,the%20school%20and%20the%20Kirk.&text=Lastly%2C%20the%20great%20schools%20called,with%20those%20apt%20for%20learning.%22

Comment: @user_1818839 - That's pretty solidly Renaissance. Early Renaissance, but Renaissance.